# Parallel computing when using ‘CORElearn' in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I’m using the ReliefF for feature selection (using the package called "CORElearn"). It worked very well before. But later on, I want to speed up my code. Since I have bootstrap in my code (each loop is doing exactly the same thing, including using ReliefF), so I’m using the package ‘parallel’ for parallel computing. But I realized that every time when it comes to the part of ReliefF, the code will just stuck there.

The related codes are as followings:

```
num.round <- 10  # number of rounds for bootstrap
rounds.btsp <- seq(1, num.round)  # sequence of numbers for bootstrap, used for parallel computing

boot.strap <- function(round.btsp) {

    ## some codes using other feature selection methods

    print('Finish feature selection using other methods')  # I can get this output

    # use ReliefF to rank the features
    data.ref <- data.frame(t(x.train.resample), y.train.resample, check.names = F)  # add the param to avoid changing '-' to '.'
    print('Start using attrEval')  # I’ll get this output, but then I'll get stuck here
    estReliefF <- attrEval('y.train.resample', data.ref, estimator = 'ReliefFexpRank', ReliefIterations = 30)
    names(estReliefF) <- fea.name  # This command needs to be added because it's very annoying that 'attrEval' will change the '-' in the names to '.'
    print('Start using estReliefF')  # I’ll never get here
    fea.rank.ref <- estReliefF[order(abs(estReliefF), decreasing = T)]
    fea.rank.ref <- data.frame(importance = fea.rank.ref)
    fea.rank.name.ref <- rownames(fea.rank.ref)  # the ranked feature list for this round

    return(fea.rank.name.ref)
}

results.btsp <- mclapply(rounds.btsp, boot.strap, mc.cores = num.round)
```

What I’m thinking now is that the function ‘attrEval’ will use multiple cores for parallel computing (I read that in the document: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CORElearn/CORElearn.pdf). Then there will be somehow conflict with the parallel that I’m using. When I change ’num.round’ to 1, then there’s no problem running the code (but even I set it to 2, it won’t work).

The server that I'm using has 80 cores.

Is there a way to solve this? I'm thinking that shutting down the parallel computing for the function 'attrEval' maybe a solution? Even though I don't how to do that~~~

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple levels of parallelism can be tricky. Unfortunately the `CORElearn` package does not allow to directly manipulate the number of threads used. Since it uses OpenMP for parallel execution, you can try to set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` appropriately, e.g.

```
Sys.setenv(OMP_NUM_THREADS = 8)
num.round <- 10
```

This way there should be 10 groups of 8 cores, each group handling one bootstrap round.

Comment: Thank you Ralf. You're right that "Having multiple levels of parallelism can be tricky". But fortunately, there's a way to force OpenMP to use only one core as what I posted later.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution from the contributor of the package Marko: disable multithreading in CORElearn by using parameter maxThreads=1 in 'attrEval'